# Spring Context Test With Just One Bean

Tags: spring-boot, spring-test, spring-boot-test

What's the recommended way to run a spring boot test where only the one subject under test is configured in the context.

If I annotate the test with

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(properties = "spring.profiles.active=test")
@ContextConfiguration(classes = MyTestBean.class)
```

Then it seems to work - the test passes, the context starts quickly and seems to only contain the bean that I want. However, this seems like an incorrect use of the `@ContextConfiguration(classes = MyTestBean.class)` annotation. If I understand correctly the class that I reference is supposed to be a `Configuration` class, not a regular spring service bean or component for example.

Is that right? Or is this indeed a valid way to achieve this goal? I know there are more complex examples like `org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.json.JsonTest` which use `@TypeExcludeFilters(JsonExcludeFilter.class)` to control the context - but this seems overkill for my use case. I just want a context with my one bean.

### Clarification

I know that I can just construct the one bean I am testing as a POJO without a spring context test and remove the three annotations above. But in my precise use case I am actually reliant on some of the configuration applied to the context by settings in the `application-test.properties` file - which is why I've made this a Spring Boot test with a profile set. From my perspective this isn't a plain unit test of a single class in isolation of the spring context configuration - the test is reliant on certain configuration being applied (which is currently provided by the spring boot app properties). I can indeed just test the components as a POJO by creating a new instance outside of a spring context, I'm using constructor injection making the providing of necessary dependencies simple but the test does rely on things like the log level (the test actually makes assertions on certain logs being produced) which requires that the log level is set correctly (which is currently being done via `logging.level.com.example=DEBUG` in a properties file which sets up the spring context).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For starters, reading the documentation first (e.g., the JavaDoc linked below in this answer) is a recommend best practice since it already answers your question.

> If I understand correctly the class that I reference is supposed to be
>   a `Configuration` class, not a regular spring service bean or
>   component for example.
>
> Is that right?

No, that's not completely correct.

Classes provided to `@ContextConfiguration` are *typically* `@Configuration` classes, but that is not required.

Here is an excerpt from the [JavaDoc for `@ContextConfiguration`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/5.0.7.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/test/context/ContextConfiguration.html):

> **Annotated Classes**
>
> The term annotated class can refer to any of the following.
>
> - A class annotated with `@Configuration`
> - A component (i.e., a class annotated with `@Component`, `@Service`, `@Repository`, etc.)
> - A JSR-330 compliant class that is annotated with `javax.inject` annotations
> - Any other class that contains `@Bean`-methods

Thus you can pass any "annotated class" to `@ContextConfiguration`.

> Or is this indeed a valid way to achieve this goal?

It is in fact a valid way to achieve that goal; however, it is also a bit unusual to load an `ApplicationContext` that contains a single user bean.

Regards,

Sam (*author of the Spring TestContext Framework*)

Comment: Thank you for the feedback - very useful and insightful, especially from an authoritative source like yourself. I'd be keen to hear your views on my specific use case - to give you the full context on this: I have a bean which uses SLF4J to log various statements. I have a test which wants to confirm that the logs are written correctly (variables and format are as expected). In order to do this the test uses a JUnit `OutputCaputre` rule. The component uses `DEBUG` level. In order for my test to work reliably I must set the log level to DEBUG or above.

Comment: Continued from above: I don't want to use a logback file for the entire test suite, I just want this one test to run with the "expected" level. I have achieved this as shown above by annotating the test as a spring test and letting spring configure the context for the duration of the test based on the content of my `application-test.properties` file - which happens to set `logging.level.com.example=DEBUG`. I can see it's "unusual" to test a single component this way given I don't need the spring context at all - I'm using a side effect of having the context (namely that the log level is set)

Answer (score 4):

It is definitely a reasonable and normal thing to only test a single class in a unit test.

There is no problem including just one single bean in your test context.  Really, a `@Configuration` is (typically) just a collection of beans. You could hypothetically create a `@Configuration` class just with `MyTestBean`, but that would really be unnecessary, as you can accomplish doing the same thing listing your contextual beans with  `@ContextConfiguration#classes`.

However, I do want to point out that for only testing a single bean in a true unit test, best practice ideally leans towards setting up the bean via the constructor and testing the class that way. This is a key reason why the Spring guys recommend using constructor vs. property injection. See the section entitled **Constructor-based or setter-based DI** [of this article](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/core.html), [Oliver Gierke's comment](http://olivergierke.de/2013/11/why-field-injection-is-evil/) (i.e. head of Spring Data project), and [google](https://www.google.com/search?q=constructor+vs+field+injection&oq=constructor+vs+field+injection) for more information. This is probably the reason you're getting a weird feeling about setting up the context for the one bean!

Comment: In addition to perfect previous explanation, if you did not used constructors in your beans you can easily setting required field by using `ReflectionTestUtils.setField` , from `org.springframework.test.util` package.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, the reason I was setting up the context in my case with `@SpringBootTest(properties = "spring.profiles.active=test")` is that the `application-test.properties` class configures some aspects of the context (settings things like log levels). I originally started without this being a spring context test  - it was a plain junit test which just created a new instance of the POJO - but I actually want the configuration to be applied as per the test properties.

Comment: @Dovmo I have upvoted but I didn't accept the answer yet as it does a good job or reenforcing some principals of good unit tests and gives good advice on DI best practices but doesn't really address whether or not the approach I've taken is a valid way of using thew spring annotations to control the context, rather, it instead suggests switching to a pure unit tests without a spring context and advocated constructor injection.

Comment: Updated per your comment! I should have initially stressed that your initial approach is a valid approach; I had to unit test a customer's Spring code once before, and I think setting up those specific beans via `@CC` is a clear and concise way to do so!

Answer (score 3):

You can also use `ApplicationContextRunner` to create your context using a test configuration of your choice (*even with one bean if you like, but as other people have already mentioned for one bean it's more reasonable to use the constructor the classical way without using any spring magic*).

What I like this way of testing is the fact that test run very fast since you don't load all the context. This method is best used when the tested bean doesn't have any Autowired dependencies otherwise it's more convenient to use `@SpringBootTest`.

Below is an example that illustrates the way you can use it to achieve your goal:

```
class MyTest {

  @Test
  void test_configuration_should_contains_my_bean() {

    new ApplicationContextRunner()
        .withUserConfiguration(TestConfiguration.class)
        .run(context -> {
          assertThat(context.getBean(MyTestBean.class)).isNotNull();
        });
  }

  @Configuraiton
  public static class TestConfiguration {
    @Bean
    public MyTestBean myTestBean(){
        new MyTestBean();
    }
  }
}
```